# SQL DB2: Want to find the count of Deleted Children based in Parent ID

Tags: sql, count, db2, parent-child

I have a table where you can see a full list of entities per type and which son is father of who

PEOPLE

```
ID  | Deleted  |  Type      | Father_id
1   |     0    |   Father   |  null
2   |     0    |   Son      |    1
3   |     1    |   Daughter |    1 
4   |     1    |   Son      |    5
5   |     0    |   Father   |  null
6   |     0    |   Father   |  null
7   |     1    |   Son      |    5
8   |     0    |   Daughter |    5
9   |     0    |   Father   |  null
10  |     1    |   Son      |    6
11  |     0    |   Father   |  null
```

I want to pull the **NumberofDeletedChildren** and **in case father doesn't have sons I have to show it as well**.

```
Father_id   | NumberOfDeletedSons
Father1     |         1
Father5     |         2
Father6     |         1
Father9     |        No Sons
Father11    |        No Sons
```

I made a query to check the total number of children, but I have no idea how to pull the number of child records deleted.

```
SELECT father, COUNT(*) AS numSons FROM PEOPLE where type in ('Daughter','Son') and deleted=0 GROUP BY father
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, start by creating a table of `distinct` fathers.  Then use an `outer join` with `count` to get your total:

```
select fathers.father_id, 
       count(children.id) NumberOfDeletedSons
from (select distinct id, type, concat(type,id) father_id
      from people
      where father_id is null) a fathers
   left join people as children on fathers.id = children.father_id
                                 and children.deleted = 0
group by fathers.father_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-join with an aggregation:

```
select f.id as father_id,
       (case when max(s.id) is null then 'No sons'
             else cast(sum(deleted) as varchar(255))
        end) as NumberOfDeletedSons
from people f left join
     people s
     on s.father_id = f.id and s.type = 'Son'
where f.type = 'Father'
group by f.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the @sgeddes answer did work for me, but with a little tweak:

```
SELECT FATHERS.FATHER_ID, 
       COUNT(CHILDREN.ID) NUMBEROFDELETEDSONS
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, FATHER_ID
      FROM PEOPLE
      WHERE DELETED=0) AS FATHERS
   LEFT JOIN PEOPLE AS CHILDREN ON FATHERS.ID = CHILDREN.FATHER_ID
                                 AND CHILDREN.DELETED = 1
GROUP BY FATHERS.FATHER_ID
```